# Can we change Bluetooth passkey programmatically in Android inspite of default 1234 or 0000? If yes, how?

Tags: android, bluetooth, passwords

How can I **programetically** change the default passkey (that is, 1234 or 0000) in [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) communication?

I mean, if I want to put the passkey (as 5674 or other) before pairing with another device then the other device must enter the same passkey I defined before the start of the pairing.

Moreover, in Bluetooth Mate Gold, how can I set my own defined key so that any user connecting to the Bluetooth mate Gold must enter that passkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to do this myself for the Bluetooth Mate (silver).

To set the device PIN, enter command mode and use the SP command as specified in the [Roving Networks Advanced User Manual](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/rn-bluetooth-um.pdf).

Example:

```
// Assumes Bluetooth Mate is connected on Serial1
Serial1.connect(115200);
// Enter command mode
Serial1.print("$$$");
delay(100);
// ... add code to read 'CMD' from Serial1 here ...
// Set PIN to '5678'
Serial1.println("SP,5678");
// Exit command mode
Serial1.println("---");
```